# How to use Photo library in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Xcode ver is 14.2.
Target iOS for 16.0.

I want to upload a image from photo library using `PHPickerConfiguration()`.
It can't appear in the `UserForm view`.

```
struct UserForm: View {
   @State var profileImage: Image?
   @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
   var body: some View {
       if profileImage == nil{
                    Button(action:{
                        isShowAction.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle.badge.plus.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                    }
                }else if let image = profileImage{
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 100,height: 100)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .clipped()
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
           .sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerPresented, onDismiss: loadImage, content:{     
                AlbumPicker(image: $selectedImage)
            }
            )
   }
}

extension UserForm{
    func loadImage(){
        guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else{ return }
        profileImage = Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct AlbumPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlbumPicker>) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .images
       
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlbumPicker>) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: AlbumPicker
        
        init(_ parent: AlbumPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            guard let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider else {
                return
            }
            
            let typeChecked = itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.map { itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier($0) }
            guard !typeChecked.contains(false) else {
                return
            }
            
            itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { (url, error) in
                guard let url = url else {
                    return
                }
                guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.parent.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.parent.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I push the button, immediately I got `findWriterForTypeAndAlternateType:119: unsupported file format 'public.heic'` using  actual device.
And it can't hold `profileImage` in the view after I chose a image in photo library.
How does it be fixed?
Thank you

Comment: It's a simulator bug. Try a different photo

Comment: `Coordinator(self)` is a mistake, self will be gone the next time this struct is init you have to implement `updateUIViewController`

Comment: Have you tried using SwiftUI's `PhotosPicker` view? Unless I'm misunderstanding the question I think you're overcomplicating it with a UIViewControllerRepresentable. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker

Comment: @malhal Hi, Malhal. Could you explain about how I should modify in  `updateUIViewController` more?

Comment: @DanO'Leary Hi, Dan. The actual test device I use is iphone SE 1st generation. The latest OS is now 15.7.3. `PhotosPicker` need more than ios 16.0. So I'm trying PHPickerConfiguration(). Thank you

Comment: @Taro, sure, in `updateUIViewController` you need to set `context.coordinator.imageBinding = $image` and in `didFinishPicking` set `self.imageBinding = image` or something like that.